# get context data in get_queryset

Tags: python, django

I have **BaseContext** and **Listview** which is for Searching in multiple models, Search Class inherits from BaseContext. I set the current user to context and want to use it in my **def get_queryset** method, But it doesn't work. I think in Search CBV **get_context_data** execute after **get_queryset** that's why, self.user is None.

```
class BaseContext(ContextMixin):
    def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
        request = self.request
        if request.COOKIES.get('token') is not None:
            ...
            user = Users.objects.filter(user_id=user_id).first()
            context.update({'current_user': user})
            context.update({'is_logged_in ': True})
        else:
            context.update({'is_logged_in ': False})
        return context

class Search(BaseContext, ListView):
    template_name = 'search.html'
    context_object_name = "results"
    paginate_by = 15
    user = None

    def get_queryset(self):
        query = self.request.GET.get('search', None)
        if query is not None and self.user is not None:
            ...
            return queryset_chain
        return faqModel.objects.none()

    def get_context_data(self, *args, **kwargs):
        context = super().get_context_data(*args, **kwargs)
        if 'is_logged_in' in context and context['is_logged_in']:
            self.user = context['current_user']
        else:
            redirect("index")

        return context
```

My question is how can I get context data in **def get_queryset(self)**?

Comment: Any reason you are not using the standard way of accessing the current user - `request.user`?

Comment: my User model is different and it is not related to Djang User model

Answer (score 2, accepted):

for Listview get_quersyset() is called before get_contex_data() , hence getting context data is not possible in get_queryset()

Comment: thanks for reply, is there any way to access context?